# How do I click on a TableView Pushbutton to open another dialogue window in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a tableView composed of 4 rows and 4 columns. In the last column I have a Pushbutton for every cell. I am trying to click on the button of every column to open another .ui form. So for 4 Pushbutton I need to open 4 equal .ui form. To be specific I will open a table to edit. How do I click on the QPush button to open a .ui form? 
Below is the **buttoncolumndelegate.h**

```
#include "buttoncolumndelegate.h"

ButtonColumnDelegate::ButtonColumnDelegate(QObject *parent) :
    QItemDelegate(parent)
{

}
    void ButtonColumnDelegate::paint(QPainter * painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem & option, const QModelIndex & index) const
{
    QPushButton detail(index.data().toString());
    detail.setGeometry(option.rect);
    detail.setText("Detail");
    painter->save();
    painter->translate(option.rect.topLeft());
    detail.render(painter);
    painter->restore();
}

void ButtonColumnDelegate::setEditorData(QWidget *editor,
                                     const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    QPushButton *detail = qobject_cast<QPushButton *>(editor);
    detail->setProperty("Detail", "Detail");
    detail->setText("Detail");
    (void) index;
}

void ButtonColumnDelegate::setModelData(QWidget *editor, QAbstractItemModel *model,
                                    const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    QPushButton *detail = qobject_cast<QPushButton *>(editor);
    detail->setGeometry(20,20,20,20);
    model->setData(index, detail->property("Detail"));

}

void ButtonColumnDelegate::updateEditorGeometry(QWidget *editor,
                              const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                              const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    editor->setGeometry(option.rect);
    (void) index;
}
```

**This is the dialog.cpp**

```
#include "dialog.h"
#include "ui_dialog.h"
#include "buttoncolumndelegate.h"

Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Dialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    mybutton = new ButtonColumnDelegate(this);
    mModel = new QStandardItemModel(4,4,this);
    ui->tableView->setModel(mModel);
    ui->tableView->setItemDelegateForColumn(3, mybutton);

}

Dialog::~Dialog()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Any clue on how to create the clickable connection as soon as I click the button and open the .ui (table) would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You doing it wrong. Editor mode in delegates - is for handle editing. You should draw a button and hadle cmouse events manually via delegate.

Or you may use [`setIndexWidget`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#setIndexWidget) on your view to create buttons.

Comment: @Emanuele Do you want me to write a code instead of you? StackOverflow is not a free coding service. There are a lot of code samples, how to use `setIndexWidget`, and there is a perfect Qt documentation. Read it, try to do and ask a question, if you will get a problem.

Comment: Hi Dimitry and thanks for the setIndexWidget direction. I was reading on Qt documentation. It seems that  it is very simple to use the command (and I did it on a small example). However I have a TableView with a delegate button where I painted inside the cell. And that confuses me when I try to modify the button to make it clickable.

Comment: No matter what I try, it gives me error when I try to use setIndexWidget on the code I provided above. If you can provide some guidance (or code) I would really appreciate that.

Comment: @Emanuele you don't need to override `setEditorData`, etc, if you are using custom painting/click handling

Comment: Hi Dimitry! Problem solved! Thank you for your last comment! I was overriding in fact. After eliminating the additional commands and working on the painting block of the code I was able to draw a button inside the rows of the tableview and make it clickable.